# Can I Contribute to Ubuntu with AliPay or Wechat?

Tags: 18.04

There is the Contribute dialog box when I download Ubuntu, and the PayPal is required for the payment. But I have no PayPal. Can I pay it with AliPay or Wecaht?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-donations-funding/29) suggests that you can contact Claire Newman for any questions you may have regarding donations.

I couldn't find any documentation regarding donating to Ubuntu using the methods you mentioned.